# input pattern mismatch while it seems to be working in regex101

Tags: html

I am making a form and I want my input to have a special pattern:

I want a number consist of 10 digits.

I want the first digit to be 9

The second digit to be 2,3,4,5 or 6

And other 8 digits could be anything from 0 to 9

This is the pattern that I have used:

```
pattern="^[9][2-6][0-9]{9,9}$"
```

I guess it works in regex but when I submit my form with a number like "9666311006" it gives me pattern mismatch error.

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

ID number: <input type="text" name="studentid" pattern="^[9][2-6][0-9]{9,9}$"  required="required">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex specifies 11 digits in total - 2 characters followed by 9. Simply change the length specifier to `{8}` to match exactly 8 characters after the first 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern actually matches *eleven* digits:

```
^[9][2-6][0-9]{9,9}$
```

If you want ten digits total, then the quantity on the final number range should be 8, not 9:

```
^[9][2-6][0-9]{8}
```

Note also that if the quantity be a fixed number, e.g. 8, then you don't need to specify a range, i.e. you may use `[0-9]{8}` rather than `[0-9]{8,8}`.